# Si c’est le cas, pourquoi dit-on « à la retraite » mais « en préretraite » dans le contexte d’arrêter de travailler ?

Tags: usage, formulation-idiomatique

Pendant une conversation avec un ami français, je lui ai dit:

> «Je ne suis pas encore  **en retraite** mais seulement **en
>   préretraite**» ...

... auquel il m’a répondu que même si  mon usage de «**en pré**retraite» était bien correct, en revanche, on dit plutôt « **à la** retraite » dans ce contexte (d’arrêter définitivement de bosser).
 (Please note that the conversation occurred during a meeting of local francophones/philes designed to help us non-natives to improve our French, so my friend’s seemingly pedantic reply was welcome and not at all out of place [unless perhaps it turns out that he was wrong].)

Pour l’usage de «à la **retraite**» dans mon contexte, il ne m’offrait comme explication que:

> «**En** retraite» s’emploie plutôt dans les contextes militaires (ou
>   dans l’expression figurative «[se] battre **en** retraite» ...

... et pour l'emploie de «en **préretraite**», il n’en offrait que «C’est comme ça».

Bien que [ce «Ngram» pour «**retraite**»](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+%C3%A0+la+retraite%2C*+en+retraite%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C*%20%C3%A0%20la%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmise%20%C3%A0%20la%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmis%20%C3%A0%20la%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdroits%20%C3%A0%20la%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Badmis%20%C3%A0%20la%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Badmission%20%C3%A0%20la%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdroit%20%C3%A0%20la%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9part%20%C3%A0%20la%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmises%20%C3%A0%20la%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bet%20%C3%A0%20la%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsonger%20%C3%A0%20la%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C*%20en%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbattre%20en%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbattit%20en%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbat%20en%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bofficiers%20en%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bou%20en%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcolonel%20en%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbattu%20en%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbattent%20en%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbattait%20en%20retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbattirent%20en%20retraite%3B%2Cc0) et [celui-là pour «**préretraite**»](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+en+pr%C3%A9retraite%2C*+%C3%A0+la+pr%C3%A9retraite&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C*%20en%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9parts%20en%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9part%20en%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmise%20en%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bou%20en%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmises%20en%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpartir%20en%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmis%20en%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bentr%C3%A9es%20en%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsalari%C3%A9s%20en%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpartis%20en%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C*%20%C3%A0%20la%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bou%20%C3%A0%20la%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdroit%20%C3%A0%20la%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bacc%C3%A8s%20%C3%A0%20la%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecours%20%C3%A0%20la%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bet%20%C3%A0%20la%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baides%20%C3%A0%20la%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bincitations%20%C3%A0%20la%20pr%C3%A9retraite%3B%2Cc0) aient l’air de confirmer tous les propos de mon ami, je ne les trouvais pas très satisfaisants pour expliquer le pourquoi.

Donc je vous demande (en France et/ou n'importe où dans la Francophonie):

> 1) Est-ce vrai que l’on dit plutôt «**à la**» (que «en») quand on parle de
>   la **retraite** dans le contexte d’arrêter de  travailler, et si c’est
>   le cas, pourquoi «à la» et pas «en» dans ce contexte?

et

> 2) Est-ce vrai que l’on dit plutôt «**en**» (que «à la») en parlant de la
>   **préretraite** dans ce même contexte, et si c’est le cas, pourquoi «en» et pas «à la» dans ce contexte?

The «why» parts of my two questions were intended to be asking (and should have been asked as the following question #3):

> 3) Are there any reasons that would or could explain why these two
>   closely related states of employment would use two different
>   prepositions to introduce them (arguably) most idiomatically?

Comment: Sur le site de Notre Temps (magazine pour les retraités) [Dit-on "à la " ou "en " retraite ?](http://jour-mot-notretemps.blog50.com/archive/2013/10/01/q-166101.html). La conclusion de l'enquête de la journaliste : « Où l'on découvre que les deux expressions sont correctes ! » Article intéressant. Je viens de consulter le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey) qui dit la même chose que le linguiste interrogé par la journaliste.

Comment: être correctes ne veut pas dire que les gens le disent. En France, on entend être à la retraite.

Comment: En France, ça dépend où. Vers chez moi (Bourgogne), « il/elle est en retraite » est assez commun, surtout chez les moins jeunes.

Comment: @Lambie Dire « être correctes ne veut pas dire que les gens le disent » est faux. En France où je vis j'entends dire et je dis « en retraite »...  La seule affirmation honnête basée sur l'expérience serait de dire que « être à la retraite » est plus fréquent que « être en retraite ».

Comment: @Lambie cela dépend totalement des régions. En Bretagne, on dit plus souvent "à la retraite", alors que là où je suis actuellement (Sud-Ouest), ils disent plus "en retraite".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En complément, c'est un cas de concurrence (d'aucuns préfèrent complémentarité) entre les prépositions [*à*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) et [*en*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en). Il y a des associations plus naturelles ou affinités entre certaines prépositions et certains sens d'un mot, même s'il n'y a pas d'autre part toujours une explication à un usage...

Mais pour la personne qui se retire d'un emploi et reçoit pension, *Ac.8* disait *à la retraite* dans sa définition de l'adjectif [*retraité*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/retrait%C3%A9) ; aussi au [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/retrait%C3%A9/1), avec la référence au synonyme *pensionné*, qui fait l'objet d'un emploi peut-être plus soutenu en Belgique (*être à la pension*) ou au Québec (*être à sa pension* ; *contra* [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2249)). L'usage varie, ajoute le *LBU14* (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §1051 d 5°) attestant aussi *à la retraite/en retraite*, et notant qu'au *Robert* on avait eu *fonctionnaire à la retraite, en retraite*. Au *DHLF/Rey* on note 1870 dans le sens en question, qu'on qualifie de métonymique, « [...] notamment dans **en retraite** et **à la retraite** (*mettre, être mis à la retraite, partir en retraite*). ». Il s'agit d'un exemple où l'on a remarqué la concurrence entre ces prépositions, tel qu'avec *lieu, place, proportion, confesse,* et *Bourse* (LBU14). Le *TLFi* discute de cette concurrence (rechercher « *Concurrence à / en* » dans le [texte de l'entrée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0)) : "La préposition *en* n'alterne avec *à* que devant certains substantif féminins et quelques substantifs masculins à initiale vocalique qui ne sont pas incompatibles avec l'idée d'intériorité. L'article livre en combinaison avec *à* une valeur de détermination, celle de généralité étant fournie par *en* qui exclut l'article ; on notera que la préposition *en* figure essentiellement dans des syntagmes plus ou moins figés." (TLFi) On nous renvoie à la section *histoire* de l'[entrée etymologique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/%C3%A0) où l'on explique certaines causes de cette concurrence. C'est qu'en latin classique on pouvait avoir *in* avec l'accusatif (mouvement et pénétration) ou l'ablatif (situation sans mouvement), et une construction avec *ad* et l'accusatif pour se diriger *vers*, ultimement atteindre mais sans dépasser. Dans une phase ultérieure de l'évolution du latin, on oppose plutôt selon le verbe *aller* ou *être*, l'un et l'autre avec la préposition *in* ou *ad* sans distinction : avec *aller* pour *à la/en/vers* la ville, sans considération de limite franchie, et *être* pour *en/à la ville*, sans considération de mouvement. La concurrence illustre au final la présence d'un nom déterminé par un article (*à la*) ou non (en) ; l'absence de l'article avec *en* pourrait illustrer un désir d'éviter la confusion avec *au* lors d'une contraction (*el, eu, ou* ; pas de nos jours évidemment) semble-t-il. Il y a d'innombrables nuances dans l'usage de la préposition selon le genre, l'initiale du mot (comme avec les fameux toponymes), le verbe utilisé etc.

---

La retraite pourrait être simplement plus *déterminée* que la préretraite, et l'usage s'enligne peut-être avec une opposition entre la retraite comme une étape précise mais pas directement compatible avec l'idée d'intériorité (le lieu), et la préretraite comme un état transitoire menant à la retraite ; c'est purement spéculatif, et en résumé on dit avec les deux prépositions *à la/en retraite*, sans doute plus avec l'une qu'avec l'autre, peut-être pour des raisons comme celles qu'on vient d'évoquer, et on est personnellement moins familier avec l'usage de la préposition avec *préretraite*, même s'il s'agit techniquement du même mot avec le préfixe [*pré-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9-). Je note par ailleurs, dans un contexte différent, que dans mon usage je conçoive qu'une personne qui *fait une retraite* (à tel abbaye) *spirituelle* soit *en retraite* (à tel abbaye) et non *à la retraite* ; ceci est compatible avec ce qui précède et généralement avec ma compréhension de l'emploi de ces prépositions.

Comment: Le _DHLF_ dans sa parenthèse articule les deux prépositions avec des verbes différents... aucun idée si c'est à dessein, mais c'est un sujet qui n'a pas fait l'objet de beaucoup d'attention dans ma réponse, le choix de verbe, sauf indirectement avec le latin aller vs. être. Les prépositions c'est un sujet vraiment difficile à mon avis. Merci !

Comment: Merci!  Riche en logique et ressources pertinentes. +1 La phrase qui contient «…un désir d'éviter la confusion…» et puis celle après qui inclut «…selon…l'initiale [le préfixe aussi, peut-être?] du mot…» me font demander s’il y aurait peut-être une confusion phonétique à éviter avec «A **la pré**retraite», i.e., «A **l’après**-retraite» (même si «l’après-retraite» n’est pas un mot)?

Comment: @PapaPoule En fait le passage sur la confusion j'ai très peu d'expertise pour le comprendre et je reproduis le TLFi... Par ailleurs dans l'exemple que vous mentionnez, et je dois dire que je suis vraiment nul avec tout ce qui touche la phonétique etc., mais entre _pré_ et _après_, la différence est très claire pour moi. _Pré_ c'est très accentué et fort, avec une brève pause avant le reste (dans mon cas), alors qu'_après_ c'est bien plus _léger_, à défaut de savoir comment dire exactement. Mais je crois qu'au TLFi on parle de confusion à un moment-clé de qqc. d'autre. Merci !

Comment: @PapaPoule About the coquille Saint-Jacques, yeah, I knew one day the joke would pop up... luckily the _coquille_ was small, not unlike the scallops they put in there, which is my only real caveat (some other word, can't remember) with that dish really. Anyways, Merry Xmas, Happy Holidays and all! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, and the same holiday wish for you and yours! Even small typos in your posts are few/rare and far between, so I must shamefully admit that I was happy to find [the] one that you made under your current moniker!  Re the meaning of "Coquille Saint Jacques," to my French wife it is the name of the sea creature itself (shell and all), but to you and other North American Francophones it seems to be the name of a dish made with the meat of those creatures (pétoncles?).  Not worthy of a formal question, but an interesting distinction, imo! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Imho it's quite worthy. I checked the Gr. Lar. Gastronomique. There is the _coquille_ per se which might have been the ancestor of the dish I'm talking about. I do also acknowledge the meaning for the shell animal but yeah, I don't think I've ever had the thing inside that shell. Usually the dish would come within the shell of the Saint-Jacques, but there would be crab meat, lobster, shrimps and scallops in a béchamel basically, which is not what the coquille is in the Larousse. Most of the times I'd buy that today the shell is some microwaveble plastic. Maybe a reg. usage. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Quand je pars **à la retraite**, j'arrête de travailler à partir d'un certain age jusqu'à la fin de mes jours.

Quand je pars **en retraite**, je me retire du monde pendant un temps plus ou moins court généralement dans un but d'introspection.

Comment: Merci! Cette distinction entre ces 2 états (l’un qui parle «d’être **à la** fin [de travailler]» et l’autre «d’être **en** passage vers cette fin» est très logique et m’aide beaucoup. +1

Answer (score 2):

1) yes, although "en retraite" would be understood as well, it does have that military meaning that would be avoided by using "à la retraite"

2) "à la préretraite" isn't idiomatic. In fact for taking time off, "en" is the word used in general, eg "je suis en vacances", "je suis en congé", "je suis en long week-end". So I'd revert the question and ask, why is it OK to say "à la retraite". I'm not sure why that usage developed.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answers (+1) and for helping me see that the "why" part of my questions was not very clear. Although I haven't reworded it to ask your interesting question, I have just now edited it to try to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: +1 for the "taking time off" bit.

Answer (score 2):

Pour la première partie de la question, je confirme (je suis français (de France)) que l'on dit « Je suis **à la** retraite », je n'ai que rarement entendu « Je suis **en** retraite ».

Par contre, j'ai toujours entendu dire « Je suis **en** préretraite » mais jamais « Je suis **à la** préretraite ».

Pour la deuxième partie, je n'ai aucune explication du pourquoi.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answers (+1). Please note that I have just now edited the "pourquoi" parts of my two questions to try to make the whole question a bit clearer.